# Disable gravity on the certain layer. Possible?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have the levitating object with a rigid body physics and, as expected, it falls down when I start the simulation.
But I want it stay still in the air (without disabling the Dynamic).

So I've tried next: I moved it to the different layer from the scene and tried to use force fields like Wind to oppose the gravity, but it moves anyway. Because I can't calculate exactly what is the opposite of -9.81 gravity force.

Any possible solutions?
Maybe the gravity can be set to zero on the certain layer?

Comment: The box for Dynamic property can be animated. Bring the cursor over it and press "I" to create keyframes.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but there are too many points of interaction, so it will take days to place all the keyframes manually like this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this process myself, but you can run a simulation in the game engine and bake it to keyframes. You could then have the levitating objects moving via keyframes and the non levitating objects being simulated. Only issue would be is if they levitating and non levitating objects interact.